# How do AppImage tools decide what .so files to include? Why produced different .so-files-including list from different distros?

Tags: dependencies, shared-library, qt, dynamic-linking, appimage

Compiled a Qt project and created `.AppImage` for it, on two different Linux distros ( Qt was installed via different ways).

The two output `.AppImage` contain different `.so` files. Both `.AppImage` run.

I want to know :

1. How do AppImage tools decide what libraries to include?
2. Why two `.AppImage` files have different libraries included, while they both run?

   Does one of them (or do both of them) have no 100% feature?

   Do they have different compatibility to various Linux distros?

I used `linuxdeploy` + `linuxdeploy-plugin-qt` like this:

```
./linuxdeploy --plugin qt --appdir ........
```

Comparison of the two `.AppImage`'s .so files:

[image]